# Javascript only add a class to an element on an interval after it's come into viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a series of images I want to transition from 0 opacity to 1 opacity when they come into the view port. I have the viewport check part done and the adding classes, however I would like them to be on an interval, so once the first 3 images come into the view port they appear 1, 2, 3 every .5seconds or so. Instead of all 3 at the same time.

here's a JS fiddle of how it works currently

```
reveal();

function reveal() {
  var reveal = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
  window.onscroll = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < reveal.length; i++) {
      if(checkVisible(reveal[i]) === true) {
        reveal[i].classList.add("fade");
      }
    }
  }
};

function checkVisible(elm) {
  var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= -200);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u04sy7jb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your code to add a `transition-delay` of an additional .5 seconds for each element after the first one, in each "group" that is revealed as you scroll. I left comments in the JavaScript so you can understand the changes.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Live demo:

```js
reveal();

function reveal() {
  var reveal = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
  window.onscroll = function() {
    // start a new count each time user scrolls
    count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < reveal.length; i++) {
      // also check here if the element has already been faded in
      if (checkVisible(reveal[i]) && !reveal[i].classList.contains("fade")) {
        // add .5 seconds to the transition for each
        // additional element currently being revealed
        reveal[i].style.transitionDelay = count * 500 + "ms";
        reveal[i].classList.add("fade");
        // increment count
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
};

function checkVisible(elm) {
  var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= -200);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.reveal {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using setInterval and it was causing a lot of errors about my variable being undefined even though it was defined above. Not sure what was going on there. But again thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: @CeeKay Happy to help! Yes, scoping variables can become hairy when using setTimeout, but there are solutions for that too. But - typically solutions avoiding JS timers are cleaner.

Comment: @JonUleis do you know why this would fail on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

You could be able to stick your `reveal[i].classList.add("fade");` inside of a setTimeout that executes as a function of your `i`th element so they show up how you're describing. Here is an example of adding short function to add the class and using it in a setTimeout to make this happen, although you could change it up to meet any additional needs.

```
function reveal() {
  var reveal = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
  window.onscroll = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < reveal.length; i++) {
      if(checkVisible(reveal[i]) === true) {
        addMyFadeClass(reveal[i], i)
      }
    }
  }
};

function addMyFadeClass(element, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add("fade");
  }, i * 500)
}
```

Comment: You're passing the index of `reveal` when you calculate the timeout, but this will result in each element of that array revealing itself .5 seconds later than the one before it - even if the element is the first element to just enter the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `:nth-child` CSS selectors without the need to change the JS:

```
.reveal:nth-child(3n+1).fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.reveal:nth-child(3n+2).fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.reveal:nth-child(3n).fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u04sy7jb/8/